# Unknown action: The action 'create' could not be found for RegistrationsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I decided to make a RegistrationsController so I can redirect the user on sign up to a specific page. Only problem is the user doesn't even get created because I get the error:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 14:01:22 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for R
egistrationsController):
```

My routes and controller:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/log_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/account_settings" => "devise/registrations#edit"
    get "/forgot_password" => "devise/passwords#new", :as => :new_user_password
    get 'users', :to => 'pages#home', :as => :user_root
  end

class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to start_path
  end

  def create # tried it with this but no luck.

  end
end
```

What's going on here? How is this fixed?

**UPDATE**

---

I put the `create` action outside of `protected` but now I get a `Missing template registrations/create`. Remove the action brings me back to `Unknown action: create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the way you've set up your `RegistrationsController`. If you take a look at [the Devise wiki page explaining how to do this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29), you'll see the following example:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

Note that the `RegistrationsController` is inheriting from `Devise::RegistrationsController` rather than `ApplicationController`. This is done so that your custom controller is inheriting all the correct behavior from Devise, including the `create` action.

Comment: I didn't even see that inheritance. I also took away the `redirect_to` since that gave a double render error. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your `create` method is `protected`, meaning it can't be routed to.

Move your `create` method out of your `protected` methods:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  def create

  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to start_path
  end

end
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me `Missing template registrations/create`. This doesn't seem correct since I'm using Devise.

Comment: You generally don't have a template to go along with a `create` action, so I'm guessing Devise doesn't provide one. Typically, you would redirect to the `show` or `index` action after a successful create.

Comment: Ah, but on a little more investigation, it looks like the lack of `create` action was a symptom rather than the root problem.